# Azure Logic App Condition is not evaluating as True or False

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to create an Azure Logic API that calls API1, gets a list of IDs then passes those IDs into another API call to API2 to see if the ID already exists.  If it does not I want it to create the ID in API2.

I've set it up as a timer-base trigger.  When triggered I have it making an API request to get a list of IDs from the first API.  It then parses the JSON so that I can use the IDs in a Foreach loop to take the IDs from one API and compare them with IDs from another API.  It's then parsing the JSON response for another foreach loop to evaluate if it exists then skip and if it doesn't create the new IDs.

The problem I'm having is when it doesn't exist in the second API it never kicks off the API request to create the IDs in the second API.  The most logical way to set it up is if API1-ID does not equal API2-ID, then true otherwise false.  The problem is, if the ID doesn't exist in API2 there's nothing to evaluate for true/false so the API call to create never execute.  I had assumed that if ID didn't exists then it wasn't equal, so it would be true.

I've even tried to use the empty expression or length if the JSON response body is zero, but I cannot get this fire off the API request to create the missing IDs.  I feel like this can work because I've flipped it to where if ID = ID then it creates the ID (which gives me duplicates).

If anyone can help that would be awesome!

[image]

[image]

Comment: you could just check if the IDs from API2 `contains` the ID from API1  ?

Comment: Thanks.  It still doesn't execute because if it doesn't exist it cannot evaluate if it's true or false.  If API-2 is not returning an ID (because it doesn't exist) the Logic App has nothing to compare, so it just skips it.

Comment: Can you show the evaluation code in your Condition? You may need to add "?" where appropriate to handle the missing property.

Comment: "expression": {
                                    "or": [
                                        {
                                            "not": {
                                                "contains": [
                                                    "@items('For_each')['code']",
                                                    "@items('For-Each-net-Code')?['Code']"
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        }

Comment: also, wasn't sure if the earlier recommendation was referring to adding Contains as one of the parameters are contains between the two parameters.